# UITableView cells not drawing until the cell is at the top of the screen

Tags: ios

I am building a table where each cell of the UITableView is a UIViewController. I have three different UIViewControllers I need to show in three rows of the table. I set the row of each cell to match the size of the UIViewController so each row is a different height.

When the app first starts, only the UIViewController in the first cell shows up. The contents of the next row doesn't show up until I scroll the table so that the top of that row is at the top of the screen. Likewise if I scroll down slightly so that a row is slightly off the bottom of the screen, when I scroll back up a little, the row contents are gone.

Here's the code I'm using. Note: The controllers to are created in the viewdidload method

What am I missing? Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:patientInformationController.view];
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:labsController.view];
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:planController.view];
            break;
        }       


        default:
            break;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewController` is a huge, high-level construct for efficiently managing entire screens of data and UI objects. `UITableViewCell` is a tiny, efficient, highly-optimized view class designed to be drawn and updated as fast as possible.

Do not, ever ever ever, add a `UIViewController's` view to the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell`. A few labels, an image, maybe a small control such as a `UISwitch` or `UITextView`.

If you haven't already, start reading [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

If you want to associate your view controllers (patientInformationController, labsController) with a particular row of the table view, the proper method is to just set the cell label for that row to a human-readable string, such as @"Patient Information", or @"Labs", and then, when the row is selected, use a UINavigationController to push the proper view controller.

UINavigationController manages a stack of UIViewControllers. A UIViewController manages a single coherent interface, usually comprised of a bunch of cooperating views. UITableViewController is a subclass of UIViewController which manages a single UITableView. UITableView is a class which specializes in the lightning-fast rendering and presentation of tabular data, organized into sections and rows according to a delegate and data source that you provide. One of the capabilities of UITableView is to inform its delegate in the event of the user selecting a row of the UITableView, allowing the delegate to present, via a UINavigationController, a new UIViewController for the presentation to the user of yet more detail and functionality.

Hope this helps. Start reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I should basically use the exact same code except in a UITableViewController? Actually, the class this code resides is in a UITableViewController

Comment: You're welcome. It sounds like you're new to iOS programming - nothing wrong with that. But based on your question, I think you've got some confusion regarding how things are put together. I think you should put in some leg work just reading docs, then get back to us. I added a little more to the answer above.

Comment: Yes, I'm new. Three months into it (coming from 25 years of Windows programming). I've been using tables a lot, but the requirements just changed to where UI got more complicated. Thus I've gone from table rows being simple labels UIViewcontrollers. I'll start reading through the docs and digging deeper. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great! Let us know if you have more questions. If I answered your question well, pls accept it by clicking the little check at left. This will help my reputation, the currency of StackOverflow.

Comment: One more thing. I noticed you said to switch views when a cell is selected. Is there a delegate called just when I scroll to make sure when any portion of the cell is visible, the proper UIViewController is shown?